# asked to calculate the logical matrix P=mn

Tags: python

I have been given some ready made code and an input and expected output now I need to find a way to calculate the output from the input

This is the code I have been given

```
3 2 4

T T
F F
T T

F F F F
T T T T

and i have been asked to calculate the logical matrix P=mn
```

resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for i in range(len(M)):
     for j in range(len(N[0])):
         for k in range(len(N)):
             P[i][j] += M[i][k] * N[k][j]
```

This is the basic schema for matrix containing integers.
You have to do 2 steps:
1) Initiate the P matrix
2) Operate with 'T' and 'F' values instead of integers.

Probably the simplest way to accomplish the step 2 is to use eval function:

```
T = 1  # eval('T') will be 1
F = 0  # eval('F') will be 0
```

And change the line:

```
P[i][j] += eval(M[i][k]) * eval(N[k][j])
```

But you still need to convert the values from P to 'T' or 'F' values. Hope this helps.

```
M = [['T', 'T'], ['F', 'F'], ['T', 'T']]             #sample values
N = [['F', 'F', 'F', 'F'], ['T', 'T', 'T', 'T']]

T = 1
F = 0

P = [] 

for i in range(len(M)):                              #result matrix creation
    P.append([None] * len(N[0]))

for i in range(len(M)):
    for j in range(len(N[0])):
        P[i][j] = 0                                  #initialization
        for k in range(len(N)):
            P[i][j] |= eval(M[i][k]) & eval(N[k][j]) #logical operators
        P[i][j] = 'T' if P[i][j] else 'F'            #conversion back to 'T' and 'F'

print P
```

This produces the output:

```
[['T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], ['F', 'F', 'F', 'F'], ['T', 'T', 'T', 'T']]
```

Comment: i believe it does but im getting an error "object of type int has no len()"

Comment: I updated the answer and included all you need. If you bring your matrix to the form in the example, you shouldn't get any errors. Notice also, how I used the logical operators (| and &), instead of arithmetical.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at http://www.syntagmatic.net/matrix-multiplication-in-python/, particularly at how the multiplication function works.